# stdbuf not working while unbuffer does

Tags: linux, bash, awk, buffer

I am trying to apply timestamps to *stdout* of a process.  For the proper timestamps to be applied, I attempt to `unbuffer` *stdout* of the process.  This works with `unbuffer` but not with `stdbuf` as I would expect.  Consider the following slow printing script '*slowprint*':

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
   echo "usage: ${0%%/*} <file> <delay in microseconds>"
   exit 1
fi

DELAY=$2 perl -pe 'BEGIN{use Time::HiRes qw(usleep)} { usleep($ENV{DELAY}) }' $
```

now compare the following attempts to apply timestamps:

```
stdbuf -oL ./slowprint <(ls) 100000 | 
awk '{ print strftime("%H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }'
```

vs

```
unbuffer ./slowprint <(ls) 100000 | 
awk '{ print strftime("%H:%M:%S"), $0; fflush(); }'
```

The second one works for me while the first one doesn't, though I expect them to do the same thing.  Currently `unbuffer` is unsuitable because it swallows error codes in certain circumstances, (I posted [a separate question about that behavior](https://superuser.com/questions/742121/unbuffer-swallows-the-exit-status-of-killed-process)).

Comment: Necroed: `perl` allows scripts to do pretty lowlevel I/O and I'd guess (but am not certain) that affects buffering. You can override it here by setting `$|=1` or with 'English' in effect `$OUTPUT_AUTOFLUSH=1`. This won't work for non-perl of course, but you may not have the problem for non-perl.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`annotate-output`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/annotate-output).  It provides timestamps for *STDIN*, *STDOUT*, and *STDERR*.

An example, use `wc` to do a line count of a `bash` *process substitution*, (one line), and a nonexistent file:

```
annotate-output wc -l <(echo foo) nosuchfile
```

Output:

```
10:17:45 I: Started wc -l /dev/fd/63 nosuchfile
10:17:45 O:       1 /dev/fd/63
10:17:45 E: wc: nosuchfile: No such file or directory
10:17:45 O:       1 total
10:17:45 I: Finished with exitcode 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the difference lies in the underlying machinery:

- `stdbuf` uses LD_PRELOAD to load a shared library that uses the `__attribute__((constructor))` annotation for a function inside it, causing it to run this function's code *before* main. That function in turn, uses the `setvbuf` functionality of libc to configure the buffers used for `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` **at startup**. Nothing stops the application to then **undo** this because it does its own `setvbuf`-ing. I believe `perl` does this, which is why your use of `stdbuf` is ignored.
- `unbuffer` works in a different way - it uses the kernel to create a pseudo-tty, thus making the application think that its stdout `isatty`; and therefore libc's behavior defaults to line-buffered output.